# How do i pass a text file to as a parameter to a stored procedure from WinForm?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, t-sql

1. Is it possible to send a **text file** of **csv** values to a **parameter** in a **stored procedure**?

   2. how do send the the **text file** from **winforms** to **stored
      procedure**?
   3. How do i create a **parameter** in **stored procedure** to accept
      that **text file**?

thanks

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Depends on the stored procedure. 3. Depends on how you want to pass a text file.

Comment: @GrantWinney the file contains 3 columns and 50 rows in csv format. what i want to do is pass the file directly into the stored procedure just like one would pass images so i dont have to create a seperate string hoping to extract text file's data from the stored procedure

Comment: @Neolisk Assume i want to send the file as a file not as a string, how would i do it?

Comment: You cannot send a file as a file. A byte array - maybe. Check this out - [Uploading and downloading files to/from a SQL Server database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225446/Uploading-and-downloading-files-to-from-a-SQL-Serv).

Comment: What do you mean with "send as a file"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the path to the file into the stored procedure as a simple "nvarchar(260)" parameter, though the Sql Server process will need to have read access to that file path (i.e., you either need to copy it to a share on the sql server itself from the WinForms app, or it needs to be on a network share that the Sql Server account has access to).

Once you have the path in the stored procedure, you can use a Bulk Insert process; see this thread on how to use Bulk Load from within a stored procedure:
[Bulk insert using stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050790/bulk-insert-using-stored-procedure)
or this thread to load it into a temp table to work with: [How to BULK INSERT a file into a *temporary* table where the filename is a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381528/how-to-bulk-insert-a-file-into-a-temporary-table-where-the-filename-is-a-varia).

That being said, a better approach would be to convert the CSV file to Xml in the WinForms app, then pass Xml as a string to the stored procedure. Sql Server 2005 and later have good support for Xml parameters, enabling you to query them. (Personally I would take this latter approach).  The Xml type is just one of the available parameter types, so you end up passing it like you would a string parameter.  Working with Xml in the Stored Procedure will be much easier (and better supported) than the CSV will be.

Comment: An important observation to make is that any path passed will be interpreted *server side*. That is, they'll be relative to the box where the DB is running, **not** the calling application. Those paths will completely break when making calling from a remote machine (even though they may seem to work in a development environment where everything is installed together)