# Use first row of CSV file as column name SQL

Tags: sql-server, import-csv

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management studio and I am currently importing some CSV files in a database. I am importing the CSV files using the BULK INSERT command into already existing tables, using the following query.

```
BULK INSERT  myTable
    FROM >>'D:\myfolder\file.csv'
    WITH
    (FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', --CSV Field Delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', -- Used to shift to the next row
    ERRORFILE = 'D:\myfolder\Error Files\myErrrorFile.csv',
    TABLOCK
    )
```

This works fine for me thus far, but I would like to automate the process of naming columns in tables. More specifically I would like to create a table and use as column names, the contents of the first row of the CSV file. Is that possible?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381528/how-to-bulk-insert-a-file-into-a-temporary-table-where-the-filename-is-a-varia but is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt more useful for this job.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is:

right-click on the database, select: Tasks -> Import Data...

After that, *SQL Server Import and Export Wizard* will display. There you have everything to specify and custom settings on importing data from any sources (such as getting column names from first row in a file).

In your case, your data source will be **Flat file source**.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer!  What I actually want is to implement it using a query. This is a requirement that has been set and it is something that would enable me to do the whole process faster. Do you have any idea on how to construct such a query?